# Run a program as a Service?

Tags: c#

I have a c# console program that backs up a SQL database on a Windows server. I want it to run every day.  I have two issues:

1- How best to run and setup this program on the server? Do I put it on task scheduler or put a timer within the program itself?

2- How can I then set up a local program to periodically retrieve the backup from the remote server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Task Scheduler is a much better idea than using a timer - you should be able to leverage your existing program to get this done

Answer (score 1):

I would use task scheduler instead of a windows service (I've had a similar situation and we decided to do the task scheduler and it was much simpler).  I'm not sure what you need to retrieve, but you could make that a scheduled task too and have it access a shared location on the server.  If it is a simple task to retrieve the backup, you could just use a batch file or powershell script.  Otherwise, you can write an app for that.

Answer (score 1):

I know that is windows server in discussion. Yet, if you want to follow the [Unix philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Mike_Gancarz:_The_UNIX_Philosophy) you may consider using [`at`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(Windows)) as your scheduler for both tasks (1 and 2).
That is: **Make each program do one thing well.**